# Loss of latex-mode Fontification When Loading Libraries in latex-mode-hook That Require json-mode

Tags: latex, font-lock, json

My actual scenario involves using `latex-mode-hook` to load some libraries that require `json-mode`.

I replicated my issue in a MWE:

I have a `LaTeX` file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

If I load it like this:

```bash
emacs -Q test.tex
```

I get this "correct" `latex-mode` fontification:

[image]

I have also a config file (I simplified it to obtain the feature):

```el
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
          (package-initialize)
          (require 'json-mode)))
```

If I load my `.tex` file like this:

```bash
emacs -Q --eval "(load-file \"/tmp/config.el\")" test.tex
```

I lose `latex-mode` fontification:

[image]

1. In the last case, to restore correct `latex-mode` fontification I need to do `M-x latex-mode`
2. This problem does not happen with other packages or custom libraries but, in my experience, it happens only for the `json-mode` package.
3. If I load `json-mode` "before" `latex-mode` I have no problem. E.g. if I modify the `config.el` file this way:

```el
(package-initialize)
(require 'json-mode)
```

and I do:

```bash
emacs -Q --eval "(load-file \"/tmp/config.el\")" test.tex
```

I get the correct `latex-mode` fontification.

Am I doing something wrong or is it some kind of bug in `json-mode` or in `Emacs`?

**Important note.**  This didn't happen with previous versions of `Emacs`. Before upgrading to version 29.2, I was using version 27 and never encountered this issue prior to the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in `json-mode.el`:

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=69404

https://github.com/json-emacs/json-mode/issues/79